# how to bind a website with static public ip address

Tags: webserver, hosting, iis-8

I have a site hosted in IIS 8 of Windows server 2012 machine. I also have the public ip address of the web server.
Now, to host the site as an public internet site and access via a domain name, can anyone please help me in how to proceed with.

As of now, I understand that I have to change the binding of the website with the public ip address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, you have to change the bindings of your web site, you do that in the IIS Manager GUI on the site level. Click `bindings` in on the right hand side and add your IP address with an empty hostname.

Or via the command line:

```
 C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config  -section:system.applicationHost/sites /+"[name='Default Web Site'].bindings.[protocol='http',bindingInformation='127.10.10.10:80:']" /commit:apphost
```

where `Default Web Site` is the name of your site and `127.10.10.10` is your public IP address.

Now assuming your network is set up correctly you can access the site in a browser by using your public IP address.

To use a host name instead, you need to have a DNS server somewhere which is the primary for your domain and that has an entry pointing to your IP address.

Before hosting a public web site, you should familiarize yourself with these concepts, or just use a company that handles all this for you.

Comment: Thanks for clarifyng me @Peter

Answer (score 1):

1. Create new account in DNSEXIT.COM

   ADD your Static Public IP inside Manage DNS service by using your DNSEXIT account
2. Bought new domain eg: yourname.com , change name server from your new domain yourname.com under manage domain
   Changes under NS1 , NS2 , NS3 and NS4 name from name server with DNSEXIT.COM name server setting
3. Access your router web admin , to change and redirect port 80 forwarded into your Web Server IP Address and DMZ should be enabled
   Make sure your port are blocked by Firewall but only open port 80 under OUTBOUND and INBOUND setting

Test your new domain yourname.com , by accessing this url with your smartphone or external internet network

Your web server now available online on public service

Answer (score 0):

You would have to approach different Providers and pay for the DOMAIN reservation. Once that is done, the would provide you with the tools con configure this domain and point to your public ip. And thats all folks!